# Post image to facebook from desktop application

Tags: facebook

I have this desktop windows app written in C#
The user can post an image to his wall from the app. I have already created the Facebook app.  In the previous version the win app would upload the image to my web site then the user was directed to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/  (via Process.Start(…) that would open the default browser) with my Facebook apppid and a redirect_uri and after authentication and obtaining an access_token the post image  dialog would open. It all worked fine.
However, my question is if I could do these  stages without a web site of my own, directly from c#.
I have seen plenty of examples but most of them refer to aspx, php and javascript but after all this is a few http request so I think it should be possible.
I think the main problem is how to get an access_token if there is no web page that the user is directed to after login.
I have seen an example using the webbrowser control but it wasn't very clear. And also, if possible I rather that the user would login using their default browser where they are most likely already logged in to Facebook and don't need to enter user and password just for this.
Also, is it possible to upload an image to facebook directly from my app without putting it on some public url first.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Uploading photos to user profiles via API is not possible at all any more, the necessary permission has been removed.

Comment: _“I rather that the user would login using their default browser where they are most likely already logged in to Facebook and don't need to enter user and password just for this.”_ - well what are you making a desktop app for then in the first place …? If I am already on Facebook in my browser, where I can upload images via the UI ... then what do I still need your app for?

Comment: @misorude I did not describe everything the application is doing as it is not relevant to the issue. however its a desktop app (and has to be so) and the user may also share on facebook what they did in the app

Comment: Well if you want to handle login in the browser where they are already logged in, then there is no other option than setting up the website platform for the app as well, perform login there, and then output their access token so that they can  copy&paste it over to your desktop application ...

Comment: (But then I doubt whether you would even get this through app review, because manually copy&pasting access tokens around is for sure rather something Facebook doesn’t want to see ... So I think you might have to go with the webview anyway.)

Comment: but if i do use the browser control then i can let the user login and get the token all "in-app" right ? something like [this](https://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-upload-image-on-facebook-using-graph-api-and-c/)

Comment: Yes, in that case everything happens “inside” your desktop app.